# Is there a way to Test (Unit/Integration) that CSS is applied to the expected HTML Elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, tdd, selenium

I am testing views with Cucumber and Rails right now and really enjoy the experience.  I can easily say:

```
Background:
  Given I am logged in as a customer
Scenario: View the Welcome Page
  When I go to the home page
  Then I should be on the "Welcome" page
  And I should see the following in the sidebar:
    | selector                  | text                |
    | h3                        | Search              |
    | .home-page                | Home                |
    | .about-page               | About               |
```

Now I'm wondering, how can I go one step further and say:

```
And I should see the following colors on the "Welcome" page:
  | selector                  | background          |
  | #content                  | white               |
  | #sidebar                  | grey                |
  | #navigation               | blue                |
```

I feel like I saw that it is possible to do this with something like Node.js or other serverside javascript, because it's all browser dependent.  Is there a way to do this, maybe with Selenium in just Safari and Firefox?

I just want to test for mainly colors and fonts, not necessarily layout b/c of the cross browser craziness.  How could I do this?  Maybe a little [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) with [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/)?

Thanks!

**Update**

Thanks to @idlefingers, here's something that works:

Setup: Cucumber, Capybara.

*features/support/env.rb:*

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

*features/step_definitions/css_steps.rb:*

```
Then /^I should see the color "([^"]+)" on the ([^"]+)$/ do |color, selector|
  element_color = page.evaluate_script('$("##{selector}").css("border-left-color");') # "rgb(221, 221, 221)"
  assert_equal color, some_color_conversion_method(element_color)
end
```

*features/some.feature:*

```
And I should see the color "red" on the sidebar
```

If there's a better way, I'd love to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand why you might want to check that the correct id or class has been applied to an element, but I can't see why you'd want to check it's css directly? That'll be so brittle - simply changing the shade of the colour will break your tests!

Also, I think you're missing cucumber's main strength - testing behaviour, not implementation. You should have a read of [this](http://elabs.se/blog/15-you-re-cuking-it-wrong) - it makes some good points which are pertinent to the way you're currently testing.

In answer to your actual question, if you really want to do this, the only way I can think of is to execute javascript on the page to test the values. This can be done in selenium (with [`get eval`](http://rdoc.info/github/ph7/selenium-client/master/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver#get_eval-instance_method)). The same thing can be achieved through capybara so long as the js driver is working.

Comment: great read!  I am going to check out that get eval and implement what that article was saying as well.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the requirement is that an element is a certain color. It is possible to test this with tools such as Jasmine, but since you want to validate the final display is right, a browser-based integration test is the right tool. (To get this to work in Jasmine, you'd have to do quite a bit more work and end up with a less valid test... anyway...)

I wrote a [simple jQuery plugin called Color Spy](http://github.com/ndp/color_spy) to be able to query an element about its colors. You can ask:

```
$(...).backgroundColor()
$(...).colorColor()
```

The plugin traipses up the DOM calculating the color.

To get this to work within the context of a selenium test, you will need to:

1. make sure the plugin is available. You can just include this in your page, or there are various ways to pull this in dynamically.
2. write an `element_color(selector)` test helper function. This will need to use the whole `get_eval` shenanigans to execute some Javascript dynamically.
3. Use `assert_equal` as normal. (I also have some Javascript function in my jsutils repo to assert "visual closeness" of colors-- but that's a different question.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Webrat (which uses Nokogiri) to test the HTML body response: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/webrat/

Then you can do:

```
assert_have_selector "#content.white"
```

Comment: That would require I add rendering-specific classes to the elements which I'd rather avoid. Looking for a full on way to check the computed css values.

Comment: I get you - I thought you were using .white as a class... good luck!